# No module named 'ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v3'

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-api-management

I am trying to work with the IBM Tone sentiment API but having difficulties getting started. I am following the documentation shown in https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer?code=python. After running the following code:

```
pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=6.0.0"
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
```

I get the following error:
`No module named 'ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v3'`

Even when trying to access  **Watson Tone Analyzer Customer Engagement endpoint to Natural Language Understanding** (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-tone_analytics). On the page it refers me back to the initial tone analysis page. [image]

I would appreciate some guidance on how to get started with the IBM on any tone analysis endpoint

Comment: In the [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding?code=python) you provided they said that "As of 24 February 2022, the Tone Analyzer tile will be removed from the IBM Cloud® Platform for new customers; only existing customers will be able to access the product. The service will no longer be available as of 24 February 2023."

Comment: I understand hence I am trying to access Watson Tone Analyzer Customer Engagement endpoint thtrough Natural Language Understanding. I have outlined this in the above question @Angerato

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the NLU module directly. If you go to the [REST API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding?code=python) for NLU Tone, on the right you can see sample code you can use.

It also explains [in a link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-tone_analytics) how to use the Tone model that replaces Tone Analyzer.

Basically you need to reference the model `tone-classifications-XX-v1` where XX is either `en` or `fr`.

Here is some sample code and output based off of the documentation.

Change `API` and `URL` to the values in the NLU instance service page-> Manage tab.

```
import json
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, ClassificationsOptions

apikey = 'APIKEY'
url = 'URL'

# Only 'en' and 'fr' available at the time of writing this.
language = 'en'
tone_model = f'tone-classifications-{language}-v1'

text = 'This is awesome! Thanks a lot! I am so happy this solved my problem.'

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
nlu = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    version='2022-04-07',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

nlu.set_service_url(url)

response = nlu.analyze(
    text=text,
    features=Features(classifications=ClassificationsOptions(model=tone_model))).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

This should generate something like this:

```
{
  "usage": {
    "text_units": 1,
    "text_characters": 68,
    "features": 1
  },
  "language": "en",
  "classifications": [
    {
      "confidence": 0.867106,
      "class_name": "satisfied"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.729703,
      "class_name": "excited"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.283219,
      "class_name": "polite"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.154289,
      "class_name": "sympathetic"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.029122,
      "class_name": "sad"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.013206,
      "class_name": "frustrated"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 0.005977,
      "class_name": "impolite"
    }
  ]
}
```